# parsing "arguments" in C++

Tags: c++, parsing

I am implementing a game in console.

I need to parse strings with escaping, I just cannot split string by space to get parameters. if one of arguments is `"Hello my name is \"someone\""` then i should get string `>Hello my name is "someone"<`

example:

```
move_player "La la" 10.0 20.0 10.0
```

this should give me 4 parameters, where I don't count command name.

```
setplayerid "La la" 24442
rename_player "La la" parameterwithoutquotes
```

Is there any library for such thing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at [boost::tokenizer](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/tokenizer/)

Use [escaped_list_separator](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/tokenizer/escaped_list_separator.htm), which separates a string using given character preserving text in quotes.

Answer (score 0):

couldn't you just use the spaces as a delimter to extract all info from the string?

sorry: mist the part about not using space.

Comment: Spaces are usually used to separate arguments. If you'd like to provide ability to enter argument with spaces inside you have to escape them somehow.